# jquery click() function returns two vars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, return

I'm new to jquery and javascript and i want the  a

```
 .click(function(e){
  /* some code and creating two vars with the position of the clicked place*/})
```

and i want to return these two vars but i don't know how.

Comment: `return {x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY};`

Comment: Create a variable in the click functions closure scope and it will be available anywhere inside that closure.

Comment: Take your pick from the properties of mouseEvent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MouseEvent

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery `.click` function returns a jQuery object. So you cannot return from inside the function. So you just need to create a var outside the click function and set it inside the function like below,

```
var elPos = {};
$(element).click (function () {
  /* some code and creating two vars with the position of the clicked place*/
  elPos.x = xpos;
  elPos.y = ypos
});
```

Comment: @BoazKatzir - Use Vega's answer. But in order to get the coordinates, pass `e` to the function like your example, and replace `xpos;` with `e.pageX;` and `ypos` with `e.pageY;`

Answer (score 2):

A function returns one value. That's how it works. But you have options.

You can return an array:

```
function foobar () {
    var x = "foo";
    var y = "bar";
    return [x, y];
}
```

You can also return an object:

```
function foobar () {
    var x = "foo";
    var y = "bar";
    return {x: x, y: y};
}
```

You can also settle for having a pair of variables in the global scope:

```
var x, y;
function foobar () {
    x = "foo";
    y = "bar";
}
```

Or pass in the object/array:

```
function foobar (obj) {
    obj.x = "foo";
    obj.y = "bar";
}
```

By the way, none of this is jQuery-specific ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 .click(function(e) {
   var x = e.pageX;
   var y = e.pageY;
   return [x, y];  

});
```

if there is an element like img then you can try this ...

```
 var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
 var y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
```